# Deploy Laravel with a bash script fails on production

Tags: laravel, deployment, production-environment

Having a production deployment bash script how can I pass in artisan confirmations?

I mean

`php artisan:migrate` stops now with the following error

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************
Command Canceled!
```

Comment: You could use this: [Forcing Migrations To Run In Production](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#forcing-migrations-to-run-in-production)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use `--force` flag.
laravel by default prevents you from running some sensitive commands in production to prevent data loss and ...
you can override this behavior by this flag.